# Mysql Query / Stored procedure to fetch data column wise based on range of month selected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-by, pivot-table, yearmonth

I select month and year with range Jan-23 to March 23. The output expected should be as shown below using mysql query or stored procedure.

|  | Jan-23 Present | Jan-23Absent | Feb-23Present | Feb-23Absent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class A | 22 | 23 | 10 | 30 |
| Class B | 22 | 23 | 10 | 30 |
| Class C | 15 | 2 | 12 | 35 |

I tried using the below query:

```
SELECT class  as 'Class', 
  sum(if(Attendance='Present',1,0))as 'Present', 
  sum(if(Attendance='Absent',1,0))as 'Absent' 
FROM attendance_data  
where date(attendance_date) between '2023-09-01' and '2023-11-01'  
group by class
```

This resulted in:

|  | Present | Absent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Class A | 1 | 2 |
| Class B | 3 | 4 |

I need the solution at the very earliest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply be able to add another condition inside your conditional sum, and use the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions to check the date:

```
SELECT class AS 'Class', 
  SUM(Attendance = 'Present' AND YEAR(attendance_date) = 2023 AND MONTH(attendance_date) = 1) AS 'Jan-23Present', 
  SUM(Attendance = 'Absent' AND YEAR(attendance_date) = 2023 AND MONTH(attendance_date) = 1) AS 'Jan-23Absent', 
  SUM(Attendance = 'Present' AND YEAR(attendance_date) = 2023 AND MONTH(attendance_date) = 2) AS 'Feb-23Present', 
  SUM(Attendance = 'Absent' AND YEAR(attendance_date) = 2023 AND MONTH(attendance_date) = 2) AS 'Feb-23Absent'
FROM attendance_data  
WHERE DATE(attendance_date) BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-02-28'  
GROUP BY class
```

If you want to make the generation of columns dynamic according to the date range, then you can use a recursive CTE to generate the statement:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE months (d) AS (
        SELECT CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(fromDate, 1, 7), '-01') AS DATE)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        FROM months
        WHERE d + INTERVAL 1 MONTH <= toDate
    ) SELECT
        CONCAT(
            'SELECT class AS "Class",',
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT_WS(',',
                    CONCAT('SUM(Attendance = "Present" AND YEAR(attendance_date) = ', YEAR(d), ' AND MONTH(attendance_date) = ', MONTH(d), ') AS "', DATE_FORMAT(d, '%b-%y'), 'Present"'),
                    CONCAT('SUM(Attendance = "Absent" AND YEAR(attendance_date) = ', YEAR(d), ' AND MONTH(attendance_date) = ', MONTH(d), ') AS "', DATE_FORMAT(d, '%b-%y'), 'Absent"')
                )
            ),
            '
            FROM attendance_data
            WHERE DATE(attendance_date) BETWEEN "', fromDate, '" AND "', toDate, '"
            GROUP BY class'
        )
    FROM months
```

The CTE at the top just generates a list of all the months between fromDate and toDate, and the SELECT part then uses this list to construct a new SQL statement using these months.

Putting this all together, you could call this from within a stored procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(IN fromDate DATE, IN toDate DATE)
BEGIN
    SET @s := (
        WITH RECURSIVE months (d) AS (
            SELECT CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(fromDate, 1, 7), '-01') AS DATE)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT d + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
            FROM months
            WHERE d + INTERVAL 1 MONTH <= toDate
        ) SELECT
            CONCAT(
                'SELECT class AS "Class",',
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    CONCAT_WS(',',
                        CONCAT('SUM(Attendance = "Present" AND YEAR(attendance_date) = ', YEAR(d), ' AND MONTH(attendance_date) = ', MONTH(d), ') AS "', DATE_FORMAT(d, '%b-%y'), 'Present"'),
                        CONCAT('SUM(Attendance = "Absent" AND YEAR(attendance_date) = ', YEAR(d), ' AND MONTH(attendance_date) = ', MONTH(d), ') AS "', DATE_FORMAT(d, '%b-%y'), 'Absent"')
                    )
                ),
                '
                FROM attendance_data
                WHERE DATE(attendance_date) BETWEEN "', fromDate, '" AND "', toDate, '"
                GROUP BY class'
            )
        FROM months
    );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

You could call this stored procedure like this:

```
CALL myproc('2023-01-01', '2023-03-01');
```

This approach is a bit fiddly - arguably this kind of logic might better be done in your application layer.  However, this should give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your response. But no this is not the expected solution, the month columns should be generated automatically based on the date range given.

Comment: I have updated the answer to describe how to make the generation of the columns dynamic according to the date range

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you. But there is a small issue. When we select different years, the data is being fetched for all the months of all the years even if there is no data for a particular month. For example, if I select date from 1st June 2022 to August 2023, and if we have data only for July 2023, same data is being reflected for July 2022 even though there is no data for July 2022.

Comment: I adapted the answer to include matching the year inside the conditional sum.  See if that works for you?